# ng-click not working when using append function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to call a function using `ng-click` when dynamical elements are created but with no success so far. Here is my code

```
$scope.myfunc = function(){
    alert("anything")
}

var divtoappend=angular.element( document.querySelector('#slist'));
divtoappend.append("<button class = 'optv' ng-click='myfunc()'>" +mybutton+ "</button>");
...
```

No error is thrown and nothing happens on click

Comment: compile a DOM with `$scope` before injecting it in DOM tree. like `divtoappend.append($compile("<button class = 'optv' ng-click='myfunc()'>" +mybutton+ "</button>")($scope));`

Comment: as @PankajParkar said also inject `$compile` service.

Comment: Thanks @PankajParkar You should post this as an answer so that I can verify it and other may find this helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to compile DOM with `$compile` API, before injecting into DOM tree, like below.

```
divtoappend.append($compile("<button class = 'optv' ng-click='myfunc()'>" +mybutton+ "</button>")($scope));
```

By compiling DOM angular will put all HTML level bindings in `$$watchers` array of `$scope` to make sure UI is up to date on every digest cycle.

Comment: What is the reason behind posting the same thing in question comment and here in the answer section?

Comment: @AKA as per OP requested in comment I did it.. Otherwise I won't be doing that.. :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to compile the dynamically generated HTML so that it is under the scope of AngularJS.
Just compile inside append method like

```
divtoappend.append($compile("<button class = 'optv' ng-click='myfunc()'>" +mybutton+ "</button>")($scope));
```

Before this inject `$compile` in your controller.

I have created a plunkr see this [plunkr link](https://plnkr.co/edit/Fa4kM1t6zR8k7cYSOv2Z?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile your DOM elements as follow using $compile

```
$compile(divtoappent)(scope);
```

Answer (score 0):

After inject {$compile} you can do:

```
angular.element('#groupList').append($this.$compile("<div id='Somevalue'> divText <button type='button' class='close' ng-click='yourFunctionHere'>&times;</button></div>")($this.$scope));
```

where: `'#groupList'` is the div that will receive the other div

Comment: Could you please clarify what your answer adds to the already existing ones?